# two eletronics with one circuit breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker

my new home has 1 circuit breaker (among others) with 220V, 2000W and 20A configuration. 
It's ok to use 2 power outlets together with this circuit breaker, in order to use 1 cooktop (gas stove) , which asks for a 2A circuit breaker, and an electric oven, which asks for a 15A circuit breaker and has 1900W max ?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: I'm from Brazil

Comment: 220 volts x 20amp = 4400 watts  if your total load is 3500 watts this would be totally legal in the U.S. The gas stove that requires 2 amps is for the ignition system that only lasts for a few seconds if I read your question correctly it would be legal here based on the loads described.

Comment: yes, the gas stove requires 2 amps for the ignition system.

Answer (score 1):

The electric oven is a high-power appliance and should have it's own outlet that has its own breaker.  I don't know anything about the electric code in Brazil, but it may even require this.

If you want other low-power outlets nearby, you can group a few on a single modest breaker.  That gives better overall protection, since the trip current for the small appliances will be less than it would be otherwise.  It also isolates better the voltage sag and other issues caused by the high power appliance.